# Deploying actix Application with nginx

Tags: nginx, rust, websocket, wss, actix-web

I created actix web & websocket within single application, and it works fine in localhost.
Basically, after passing a login page, it opens a dashboard and a common Javascript's `WebSocket`.

```js
new WebSocket(`ws://server:8181/client?token=${TokenString}`);
```

And it works fine.
I don't want to expose this 8181 port on my production server, so my plan is using a sub path `/ws` to map to 8181 port.

So my `/etc/nginx/sites-enabled/default` config is:

```
server {

       server_name my_domain.com; # managed by Certbot

        ....
        #WebSocket part is here, under /ws path and mapped to 8181 port
        location /ws {
           proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
           proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
           proxy_set_header Host $host;
           proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy false;
           proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8181;
           proxy_redirect off;
           proxy_http_version 1.1;
           proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
           proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
        }

        #Here is my web app, / mapped to 8080 port
        location / {
            client_max_body_size 50m;
            client_body_buffer_size 50m;
            proxy_pass http://127.0.0.1:8080;
            proxy_set_header X-Real-Ip $remote_addr;
            proxy_http_version 1.1;
            proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
            proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
            proxy_set_header Host $host;
            proxy_cache_bypass $http_upgrade;
        }

        location ^~ /\. {
           deny all;
        }

        #configs generated by Certbot
        listen [::]:443 ssl ipv6only=on; # managed by Certbot
        listen 443 ssl;
        #...
}

#redirect http to https
server {
    if ($host = my_domain.com) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


        listen 80 ;
        listen [::]:80 ;
    server_name my_domain.com;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot


}
```

My web page `https://my_domain.com`, works fine. But my mapped WebSocket connection doesn't.

```js
new WebSocket(`wss://my_domain.com/ws/client?token=${TokenString}`);
```

With just `WebSocket connection to ... failed:` message, and `/var/log/nginx/error.log` shows nothing.
Is something wrong with my nginx config?

*Edit: it turns out showing 404 in `/var/log/nginx/access.log`

Comment: looks like you are missing upstream https://stackoverflow.com/a/54087298/175554

Comment: @ozkanpakdil I'm afraid it's not. The ```/ws``` should be URL rewritten. I just posted my own answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out, the `/ws` path should be URL rewritten since my websocket didn't map `/ws` to anything.
The idea was from [here](https://serverfault.com/a/693951)

So my configuration is:

```
location ~* ^/ws/ {
           rewrite ^/ws/(.*) /$1 break;
....
```